# Adding/removing an object into array and also check if object already exits

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I have a task, where I need to push an object into an array ,before pushing need to check whether the object already exits if so need to delete/remove the object from array.
I have written sample code and I'm not getting the output as expected.

```
optionlistItemTap : function (data, index) {
    var record = data.getStore().getAt(index);
    var Id = record.raw.id;
    var arraysize = names.length;

    for (i = 0; i <= arraysize; i++) {
        if (arraysize == 0) {
            names.push(record);
            var indexId = names[i].raw.id
            var Id = record.raw.id
            break;
        }
        else if (indexId == Id) {
            names.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
        else
        names.push(record);
    }
},
```

Comment: We can't help you fix partial code: What are `names`, `indexId` in the `else if`, and the content of `record`? And how are you calling that function, what exactly do you expect it to do, and what does it do? Also, you're missing accolades (`{}`) at your last `else`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, my best guess is that you need this:

```
optionlistItemTap : function (data, index) {
    var record = data.getStore().getAt(index); // Get the record
    var Id = record.raw.id;                    // Get the record's id
    var arraysize = names.length;              // Get the length of the `names` array

    if (arraysize == 0) {                      // If the `names` array is empty,
        names.push(record);                    // Push the record to the array.
        return;                                // Break out of the function.
    }else{                                     // Otherwise,
        for (var i = 0; i <= arraysize; i++) { // Loop through the array,
            if (names[i].raw.id == Id) {       // And if names[i]'s id matches the id of the element to add,
                names.splice(i, 1, record);    // Replace the element in `names` with the record.
                return;                        // Break out of the function.
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: @sra: You can't use `indexOf` for complex Objects. For example, in: `var a = {a:1}; var b = [{a:1}];`,  `b.indexOf(a);` will return `-1`.

Comment: I will remove the misleading comment. I've never tried to lookup complex objects that way but I guess you are right. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

indexId is undefined in else if block